# clone() method does not throw RuntimeException been called on object of class unimplemented Cloneable

Tags: java, clone

Test case (jdk version: oracle 1.6.0_31)

```
public class TestCloneable{
    public TestCloneable clone(){
        return new TestCloneable();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestCloneable testObj = new TestCloneable();
    TestCloneable testObj2 = new TestCloneable();

    System.out.println(testObj.clone());

    Hashtable<Integer, TestCloneable> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, TestCloneable>();
    ht.put(1, testObj);
    ht.put(2, testObj2);
    System.out.println(ht.clone());

    HashMap<Integer, TestCloneable> hm = new HashMap<Integer, TestCloneable>();
    hm.put(1, testObj);
    hm.put(2, testObj2);
    System.out.println(hm.clone());

}
```

None of these lines gives CloneNotSupportedException in runtime which contradicts java specification on clone method: 

   `/**
     * @exception  CloneNotSupportedException  if the object's class does not
     *               support the Cloneable interface. Subclasses ...
    */`

Where is mistake?

Comment: In using clone?  Clone is sort of broken in general.

Comment: In general. I mean is it my mistake in usage clone or some bug in jdk?

Answer (score 3):

According to [javadocs for hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#clone%28%29) :

```
clone()
Returns a shallow copy of this HashMap instance: the keys and values themselves are not cloned.
```

So the method `clone()` is never called on your class.

Moreover, if you want to benefit from the behavior of the `clone()` method in `Object` and have an exception thrown when the object doesn't implement `Cloneable`, you should call `super.clone()` in the overrided method `clone` of your class.

Comment: Thanks! The right test case will be public class TestCloneable {
 public TestCloneable clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  TestCloneable tc = (TestCloneable)super.clone();
  return tc;
 }
}